# Default Account not having password error

Tags: postgresql

One of vulnerability scans are showing "PostgreSQL Default Unpassworded Account". Have 2 user accounts and the Postgres account only on server and all 3 have been altered to have a complex password and can be seen in pg_shadow.

pg_hba.conf has the following. Would this be the cause of the issue? Even so if password is setup for the accounts why would the scan claim unpassworded account?

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createuser.html) version of 9.6 or less, then

The [user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createuser.html) must be created using `UNENCRYPTED`

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'test_password';
```

and

`trust` will allow all users to connect to PostgreSQL without any password.

Change it to `md5`

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: Just be aware that in Postgres 11+ scram is the recommended password method and that it will become the default in version 14. You might want to future-proof by using that. The caveat is that older versions of  clients may not support it.

Comment: What is the point of setting up a password for the user that shows up in pg_shadow, if the pg_hba.conf allows any account to log into with the trust option? CREATE USER test_user WITH UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'test_password' - how can this be done for the postgres account which is the master account and cannot be dropped?

Comment: trust is not the reason why it shows in pg_shadow. The user might be created using `UNENCRYPTED`

Comment: `UNENCRYPTED` was available up to version 9.6. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createuser.html. It got removed from version 10.

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to ask the vendor or the documentation of the security test program to know for sure, but it is likely that it complains about the `trust` in `pg_hba.conf`, which is indeed a security problem of the first order if it allows a superuser to login remotely without a password.

For best security, I have two recommendations:

- Only allow superuser logins from local OS accounts on the database server machine.
- Use one of the more advanced authentication methods that does not rely on a password stored in the database.